# Ultrasonic distance measuring conflict about time, arduino code

Tags: arduino, arduino-uno, arduino-ide, arduino-c++

```
---8<-----this is my code--------------------------
 #include <MsTimer2.h>
int distance;
void setup() {
  MsTimer2::set(500,IRQ_Timer);
  MsTimer2::start();
  pinMode(11,OUTPUT);
  pinMode(12,INPUT);
}

void loop(){

}

void IRQ_Timer(){
  echo();
}
//this echo section
void echo(){
  unsigned long p_time=millis();
  while(1){
    unsigned long c_time=millis();
    digitalWrite(11, LOW);
    delayMicroseconds(2);
    digitalWrite(11, HIGH);
    delayMicroseconds(10); 
    digitalWrite(11, LOW);
    distance = pulseIn(12, HIGH)/58.3;
    if(c_time>=p_time+5){
      break;
    }
  }
  return;
 
}

> ---8<------------------------------------------------------
```

This code is related to ultra-sound-distance-section. We want the robot to measure distance, in order to define when  to stop, but the echo section(whole thing in void echo() takes more time than we expect to deal with, when the code finishes its judgement, the robot has already run out of parking zone
How should I reduce the time for void echo(), or make this code coordinte with each other?

How should I reduce the time for void echo(), or make this code coordinte with each other?

Comment: ultrasonic sensors use sound, which takes time to travel and therefore they are slow at measuring distances. Have you considered using a sensor that uses light instead? they are cheap and much much faster. something like this https://www.adafruit.com/product/3317